# Question about setTimeout and fs.readFile in nodejs event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, event-loop

I have this code in a node app :

```
const fs = require("fs");

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("timeout");
}, 1000);

fs.readFile("read.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The file that is being read contains only the word 'hello';

In node the first phase is for timers, so the setTimeout will be called and executed in the callstack, and that callback function that the timer have should go into the timers queue from event loop.
After that the readFile is executed in callstack and the callback from it will go to I/O queue which would be the second phase in a event loop cycle. Finally the callback from the first phase should be moved from queue and executed in the callstack after the delay is over. I don't understand why it skips that first phase and instead it executes the callback from the fs;

Comment: I guess that's because it happens before 1000 ms

Comment: You are not using the term "callstack" correctly here.

Comment: There's one event queue, it's used for all async events. The callbacks are run in the order that their triggering events occur. Since `readFile()` finishes before the timer triggers, you get that output first.